# Prove that $gcd(G_b,b)=1$

Tags: proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm, euclidean-domain

I'm doing some exercise on Euclidean space and Euclid's algorithm, but I can't prove the following statement:

[image]

**NOTE**: I'm interested only on the first point (**a**) and **if possible** I don't want a direct solution I prefer some **hints** so that I can work on it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Prove (a) by induction. If $G_n=aG_{n-1}+bG_{n-2}$ and $\gcd(G_{n-1},b)=1$, what can you say about a common divisor for $G_n$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Show by strong induction that $G_n=a^{n-1}+bX_n$.